# Separating the common name when extracting data from a json format

Tags: json, jsonpath

I do have this sample json data that I got from jsonplaceholder, a dummy rest api data. I am practicing display/fetching data to it.

Now, I am having a trouble when I am fetching the name of the person. But look at the company, it also has the attribute name to it.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
```

so whenever I try to use `$..name` it displays the company name as well, which is I do not want I only want the name of the people. How do I separate it the name of the person and the name of the company.

I am using [jsonpath](https://jsonpath.com/) as my playground to practice.

any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello, @JoachimSauer. Can you post your answer so I could accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jsonpath for this query would be `$[*].name` which means "for any element in the root array get the `name` field". This avoids using `..` which is interpreted as recursive descent (i.e. looking at any and all child objects).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this following script:

```
const dataJson = require('./data.json');

function main() {
    for (let i = 0; i < dataJson.length; i++) {
        console.log(dataJson[i].name)
    }
}

main()
```

In your case, I got this output:

```
$ node index.js 
Leanne Graham
John Carmack
Mickael Jordan
```

With this Json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John Carmack",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mickael Jordan",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  }
]
```